# Can you edit a Postgres ArrayType in C?

Tags: c, postgresql, function

I'm trying to write a PostgreSQL function and am storing an ArrayType *state that needs to change each time I call the function. Do I need a separate Datum array to use in construct_array each time I call the function or can I change values in state directly (i.e. state[i] = 10)?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you'd store a Datum array and only `construct_array` at the end when you're going to return values.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do not directly modify an `ArrayType`.

Since it is a `varlena`, you'd have to `repalloc` it and shift around values whenever elements are added or removed and maintain the `varlena` header and the NULL bitmap. You'd have to use `dataoffset` and iterate through the elements.

Either keep your state in an ordinary C array and use `construct_array` whenever you need an `ArrayType` (this is probably less expensive and better) or use the functions `array_get_element`, `array_set_element` and others from `utils/array.h` to operate on an `ArrayType`.